# Execute python based model in scala based spark Structured Streaming program

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, spark-structured-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

I have a scala based structured streaming program that needs to execute a Python based model.

In previous version of spark (1.6.x), I used to do that by converting DStream to RDD and than invoking rdd.pipe method.

However, this approach does not work on structured streaming. It gives the following error:

> Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()

The snippet of code is as follows:

```
val sourceDF = spark.readStream.option("header","true").schema(schema).csv("/Users/user/Desktop/spark_tutorial/")
val rdd: RDD[String] = sourceDF.rdd.map(row => row.mkString(","))
val pipedRDD: RDD[String] = rdd.pipe("/Users/user/Desktop/test.py")

import org.apache.spark.sql._
val rowRDD : RDD[Row] = pipedRDD.map(row => Row.fromSeq(row.split(",")))


val newSchema = <code to create new schema>

val newDF = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, newSchema)
val query = newDF.writeStream.format("console").outputMode(OutputMode.Append()).start
query.awaitTermination()
```

The Exception stack trace:

> 19/01/22 00:10:00 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
>   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
>   FileSource[/Users/user/Desktop/spark_tutorial/]
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$UnsupportedOperationChecker$$throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:374)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$$anonfun$checkForBatch$1.apply(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:37)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$$anonfun$checkForBatch$1.apply(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:35)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:126)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.checkForBatch(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:35)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertSupported(QueryExecution.scala:51)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:62)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData(QueryExecution.scala:60)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:66)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:66)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.rdd$lzycompute(Dataset.scala:2975)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.rdd(Dataset.scala:2973)
>       at Test$.main(Test.scala:20)
>       at Test.main(Test.scala)

Any suggestions?

Comment: any ideas or thoughts?